# Get child records of selected rows from database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 tables like so

bug_groups

```
ID        NAME        DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------
1         Group1      Some description
2         Group2      Some description
3         Group3      Some description
```

bugs

```
ID        NAME        DESCRIPTION        BELONGSTO
--------------------------------------------------
1         Bug1        something          1
2         Bug2        something          1
3         Bug3        something          2
```

bug_comments

```
ID        BUGID       COMMENT
-----------------------------
1         1           something
2         1           something
3         2           something
4         2           something
5         3           something
```

I want to create a stored procedure that will get 2 result sets, one with all the bugs for a given bug group and one with all the comments for all of the bugs in the group. The `BELONGSTO` field specifies which group that the bug is a part of. So If I wanted to run this query, passing in 1 for the bug group ID I would expect this result

```
RESULT SET 1

ID        NAME         DESCRIPTION         BELONGSTO
----------------------------------------------------
1         Bug1         something           1
2         Bug2         something           1

RESULT SET 2

ID        BUGID        COMMENT
------------------------------
1         1           something
2         1           something
3         2           something
4         2           something
```

I think I may need to use a temporary table but I'm unsure how to do this. This is what I have so far (which doesn't work)

```
ALTER PROCEDURE bugs_getAllBugGroupData
    @groupid int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @bugids TABLE (id int)
    INSERT @bugids
    SELECT id FROM bugs
    WHERE belongsto = @groupid

    SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE belongsto = @groupid
    SELECT * FROM bugs_comments WHERE bugid IN (@bugids)
END
GO
```

The error message I get is "Must declare the scalar variable @bugids" at the last select statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
SELECT * FROM bugs_comments WHERE bugid IN (@bugids)
```

has to be

```
SELECT * FROM bugs_comments WHERE bugid IN (SELECT id FROM @bugids).
```

However you don't need an auxiliary table. You can query directly using a join:

1.

```
SELECT * FROM bugs WHERE belongsto = @groupid
```

2.

```
SELECT * FROM bugs_comments AS bc
    INNER JOIN bugs AS b ON (bc.bugid = b.id)
    WHERE b.belongsto = @groupid
```

Comment: Oh my god your right! Note to observers: don't over complicate it. Thanks, will mark it in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

a more efficient way is...

```
SELECT  ID,
        Name,
        Description,
        BelongsTo
  FROM  bugs
 WHERE  BelongsTo =  @groupid 

SELECT  bc.ID,
        bc.BugID,
        bc.Comment
  FROM  bug_comments bc
        JOIN bug b ON b.BugId = bc.BugID AND b.BelongsTo = @groupid
```